Integral form of cdf in Python
I want to use a mathematical model of this kind. How do I find the exact integral form of cdf(x) which Python uses in this context?
from scipy import stats

def model(x, x0, s, A, c):
    law = stats.norm(loc=x0, scale=s)
    return A * law.cdf(x) + c


from which package is stats?

scipy. I have edited now.

Not clear quite what your question is asking, but for the normal distribution the cumulative distribution function can mathematically be written in terms of the error function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).
Your model (multiplying by A and adding C) can be written in any of the forms below, depending on whether you want to write it explicitly in terms of the error function and whether you want to take your integral limits from 0 or -infinity.

Code using the error function mathematical routine is given below. There are many ways that the underlying library routine might evaluate the integral other than actually attempting a numerical evaluation of that integral.
import math
from scipy import stats

def model(x, x0, s, A, c):
    law = stats.norm( loc=x0, scale=s )
    return A * law.cdf( x ) + c

def normal_CDF( x, x0, s ):
    return 0.5 * (   1 + math.erf( (x-x0)/s/math.sqrt(2) )   )

def alt_model( x, x0, s, A, c ):
    return A * normal_CDF( x, x0, s ) + c


x, x0, s, A, c = 5.92, 2.0, 2.0, 10.0, 5.0
print( model( x, x0, s, A, c ) )
print( alt_model( x, x0, s, A, c ) )

Output:
14.750021048517794
14.750021048517796


But isn't the limit of the integral from 0 to x instead of -inf  to x according to the definition of error function?

The error function is equivalent to an integral with lower limit 0, but then you also have to compensate by writing the CDF as (1/2)[1+erf(.)] and not just erf(.) itself. You can write the integral form in many different forms, depending on where you want to set the lower limit and whether you want a scaled integral. I have amended the post to show that. As an explicit integral, the last form simply shows the CDF being the integral (from -infinity) of the normal-distribution PDF ... which is what a CDF is defined as.
